# Powershell- Create readable Security message data from Event Log

Tags: powershell, active-directory, event-log

The goal: Get the deleted and created Organization Units in Active Directory via PowerShell `Get-EventLog`.

The problem: Any results of a search against event ID 4662 result in the following:

```
An operation was performed on an object.

Subject :
    Security ID:        S-1-5-21-3179159395-111441685-1606651853-500
    Account Name:       Administrator
    Account Domain:     FRANKDC1
    Logon ID:       0x53f92

Object:
    Object Server:      DS
    Object Type:        %{bf967aa5-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2}
    Object Name:        %{484859f8-78ce-446f-84fd-e98e060c3b2f}
    Handle ID:      0x0

Operation:
    Operation Type:     Object Access
    Accesses:       %%1537

    Access Mask:        0x10000
    Properties:     %%1537
    {bf967aa5-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2}
d

Additional Information:
    Parameter 1:        -
    Parameter 2:
```

As opposed to what you see when you pull up the entry from the EventLog window:

[image: Eventlog screenshot]

Here's what I run:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | Where {$_.EventID -eq 4662} | Select -ExpandProperty Message
```

I'm of course filtering further for what results I've posted, but this is the core of what I've come up with so far.

I would ideally like to extract "Operation.Accesses" and "Object.ObjectName" for my report. Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Note: Get-WinEvent gives me slightly more information, but I still do not get the Object Name which contains the DN of the OU that was deleted (in this specific example)

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Comment: Sure thing. What I have now is this: 

Get-EventLog -LogName Security | Where {$_.EventID -eq 4662} | Select -ExpandProperty Message

Of course I can drill into a specific event, this query will give me all 4662s, but this is the code I run to get the results I've already posted. 

I'm not sure how to be more clear. That is the command I ran, I've shown my output and I've shown the expected results. I'm not asking for handouts, I'm asking for assistance. 

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question.